# Round up floating thousandth place 5s up in Python

Tags: python, rounding, floating-accuracy

I'm using this function to round up floating 5s in Python:

```
def round_half_up_xx(n, decimals=2):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.floor(n*multiplier + 0.5) / multiplier
```

I'm getting weird results:

- round_half_up_xx(81.225) => 81.22
- round_half_up_xx(81.235) => 81.24

How do I revise the code so that round_half_up_xx(81.225) yields 81.23?

Comment: Take a look at [```Decimal```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module. It already implements rounding functions the way you want. From there "Rounding options include ROUND_CEILING, ROUND_DOWN, ROUND_FLOOR, ROUND_HALF_DOWN, ROUND_HALF_EVEN, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_UP, and ROUND_05UP."

Comment: @KentShikama: The problem here isn't banker's rounding/round-half-even, it's floating point imprecision that makes all round-half strategies irrelevant. I've redirected to a question that addresses that specific problem.

Comment: `math.ceil(n*100)/100`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel: That's unconditional rounding up, not rounding *halves* up. `81.220000000001` would round to `81.23` under your approach, when they only want `81.225` (and higher) to round to `81.23`, and any number below `81.225` to round to `81.22`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I missed the _halves_ up part. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because `81.225` isn't a real value in IEEE 754 binary floating point. It's shorthand for `81.2249999999999943...`, which, as it doesn't end with a `5` in the thousandths place, rounds to `81.22` without concerning itself with special rounding rules.

If you want true accuracy of this sort, you'll need to use [the `decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), initializing the `decimal.Decimal` values with `int`s or `str` (if you initialize with `float`, it will accurately reflect the precision of the `float` as best it can, so it won't be `81.225` either). With decimal precision, it can do decimal rounding with whatever rounding strategy you like, without reimplementing it from scratch like you've done here.